# What do you call the process that makes use of an API?

Tags: api, rest, terminology

At my work the term API is thrown around loosely.

It's often used to describe automated processes composed of batch files, scripts, SQL stored procedures, SQL jobs, Windows tasks, etc.

It confuses my boss and management when I try to talk about an actual API, the *interface* (i.e., a vendor's protocol for what endpoints to use, how to pass keys, call limits, access token use, expected JSON structure, where to pass particular parameters, how errors should be interpreted, etc.) I tried to explain that this is the more literal definition, and refer to the piece I'd develop as the process that interacts with the API. I feel like I'm only confusing them more though.

Is there a term for the process one develops to interact with an API to automate things? If there's no specific term, how do you refer to it?

Comment: Generally either a "client" or a "peer" (depending on whether it is a client-server API or a P2P API)

Comment: I like this, but (to me) it connotes a compiled or more unitary process. For my particular situation I like the answer @wickdninja gives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At my current position, we tend to call this process “integration”.  We are integrating the external or internal API with another backend process or with a front end client application.

Comment: Thanks! I like this answer. I'm going to start using this. I think my question is relatively subjective (unless there's a widely accepted textbook definition out there,) so marking this as the answer.